# VS2010 Build Exception caused by ReSharper; SetEnvironmentVariable task not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, build, resharper

I've had a problem with my Windows 7 after an update, neither Safe Mode nor Recovery Mode could resolve the problem. I was forced to reinstall Windows completely. To develop on my projects I need Visual Studio 2010.

I always had ReSharper installed and got used to its features, so I installed it aswell.

Everything setup I tried building my solution but encountered a problem ...
[image: img1]
(The underlined file can be found here: https://up.zone/aj)

After hours of trying to resolve the problems, I figgured out that ReSharper was the problem. I can build the solution perfectly fine without ReSharper installed. Having it installed, even if all features are turned off and the services are suspended, causes these errors in the picture above to show on build.

I managed to resolve two out of three errors by following the instructions of this Reddit user on his post: https://up.zone/ag

Now I am left with one more exception I cannot figgure out how to resolve. I couldn't really find anything helpful googling, which means you guys are my last hope. I really do not want to go back to developing without ReSharper.

This is the one:
[image: img2]

Any idea?

Thank you!

---

**Update 1**

I figgured out that the problem must be in the `NuGet.targets` file, located in the `.nuget` folder in our solution.

I managed to find a workaround following the suggestion of [this post](https://up.zone/aL), I am now able to build the solution without any errors.

To summarize, remove this line out of your *.csproj file

> `<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />`

Although this works, I don't think this can be the solution. This line is there for a reason I assume. Anybody with a deep understanding of NuGet who might know how to properly resolve this problem?

---

**Update 2**

I found out that as soon as you reload your solution/project, the line gets added once again. Also, if you have certain dependencies nuget should download for you - it won't, because the line which makes that call and handles this got removed.

I'm now at a point where I know where the problem is but not why it is caused.

Does ReSharper change anything in the way NuGet behaves? As far as I can tell, nothing gets added or removed to or from the `NuGet.targets` file due to ReSharper.

Comment: For what it's worth: I think the SetEnvironmentVariable referenced Task here is the one that's usually declared  by code analysis (roslyn). It's not present in a compiled DLL but directly in a .targets file. On my PC, it's present in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets and C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets.

Comment: @SimonMourier since I don't have VS 14 installed, there isn't a folder called `CodeAnalysis` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\`, however there is one in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0`.

Regardless of that, the exception sais that `the task cannot be found`, so I assume that there is something missing inside that file. Do you mind providing your file for comparison?

Comment: I have another machine with v10.0 and the Micr‌​osoft.CodeAnalysis.T‌​argets file in there doesn't define SetEnvironmentVariable. I guess that's the root of the problem. Some code on your machine requires a more recent version of this. I suggest you install msbuild 2013 (v12): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760 and/or msbuild 2015 (v14), as msbuild is not shipped exclusively with VS today, but is an independent tool/redist (it's even open source now actually).

Comment: @SimonMourier this doesn't seem to help at all :/ it also didn't create the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\V12.0\` where the necessary file would be, instead it created the `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0` folder if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: Do you have the SetEnvironmentVariable created in the files there? Have you tried the 2015 version?

Comment: @SimonMourier how? there is nothing like that to be found in the file. I cannot upgrade to a newer version, I'm stuck with VS2010 due to dependency issues

Answer (score 1):

There were one more report on this topic, at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-462271 .

The best guess so far is that this is caused by two things happening at once: (a) using MSBuild tasks in C# source code form inside MSBuild XML files rather than DLLs and (b) having some of the MSBuild opensource DLLs shipped with the latest version of ReSharper for its own project file handling needs.

The source code gets compiled into a task DLL during an MSBuild run (not a much common thing to have; Roslyn would do this rather than ship a DLL? seriously?). When building from within Visual Studio (rather than with `msbuild.exe`), the in-process MSBuild instance is used, and it would run in the same appdomain as ReSharper, so it uses the common assembly reference resoluiton. If it's not too accurate, then it might accidentally pick the wrong DLL version by the short name, which would break the task compilation (that's a separate error, maybe cached away) and then result in the task-not-found error later at runtime (`SetEnvironmentVariable task not found` in here case).

I've tested on sample solutions with source code based tasks and could not get it broken. So trivial cases are OK. Never heard back from the original issue reporter, so there was no further progress.

Now I've got a hint that this is Visual Studio 10 (any other VS versions installed on that machine?) and maaaaybe it's Roslyn tasks. We might know for sure if you run MSBuild with more detailed logs (by setting the logging options at Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Build and Run | MSBuild project build output verbosity to at least Detailed) and building just the faulty project.

I'll also try this out with VS10 and update this reply with new data.

Comment: I have only VS2010 installed (the following components https://up.zone/av) as well as VS2008 C++ components because we have few older projects which need this specific compiler provided in that version. We cannot use a newer version because we use a certain report feature which got removed in the newer versions, so basically I'm stuck with VS2010 until we update the dependencies.

Comment: also, I wasn't able to replicate the error in a newly created solution. it just happens to 2 out of 102 projects in our solution. I cannot see what's different in those projects, they seem to be perfectly fine :s

Comment: How about the detailed MSBuild logs? They should reveal the difference, I so hope.

Comment: I try to provide as much information as possible. I installed R# with the following settings https://up.zone/aw . During the installation I had ProcessMonitor open to capture every step it makes, the log file can be found here https://up.zone/ax (P.M. needed to open it). I also built the failing project several times with the different verbosity levels - the build outputs can be found here https://up.zone/ay . If you need anything else for your analysis just let me know.

Comment: also, I built the project with and without R# installed, the output log (verbosity: detailed) can be found here https://up.zone/az .. if you diff them you'll see that there is no difference at all except in the last part where it tries to build itself. With R# installed, it crashes at that part with `SetEnvironmentVariable` ..

Comment: I updated my original question, do you know what role nuget plays in R# ?

Comment: ..anything new?